# Understanding next step after saving TensorFlow model

Tags: python, tensorflow, mnist

I've a simple MNIST which I've successfully saved, being the code the next:

```
from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data
mnist = input_data.read_data_sets('MNIST_data', one_hot=True)
import tensorflow as tf

sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
tf_save_file = './mnist-to-save-saved'
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 784])
y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 10])
W = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([784, 10]))
b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([10]))
saver = tf.train.Saver()

sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

y = tf.matmul(x, W) + b
cross_entropy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels = y_, logits = y))

train_step = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.5).minimize(cross_entropy)
saver.save(sess, tf_save_file)

for _ in range(1000):
    batch = mnist.train.next_batch(100)
    train_step.run(feed_dict={x: batch[0], y_: batch[1]})

correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(y, 1), tf.argmax(y_, 1))
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32))
saver.save(sess, tf_save_file, global_step=1000)

print(accuracy.eval(feed_dict={x: mnist.test.images, y_: mnist.test.labels}))
```

Then, the next **files** are **generated**:

```
checkpoint
mnist-to-save-saved-1000.data-00000-of-00001
mnist-to-save-saved-1000.index
mnist-to-save-saved-1000.meta
mnist-to-save-saved.data-00000-of-00001
mnist-to-save-saved.index
mnist-to-save-saved.meta
```

Now, in order to use it in production (and so, for example, pass it a number image), I want to be able to **execute the trained model** by **passing** it any **number image to make the prediction** (I mean, not deploying yet a server but making this prediction "**locally**", having in the same directory that "fixed" number image, so using the model would be like when you run an executable).

But, considering the (mid-low?) API level of my code, I'm confused about what would be the easiest correct next step (if restoring, using an Estimator, etc...), and how to do it.

Although I've read the official documentation, I insist that they seem to be many ways, but some are a bit complex and "noisy" for a simple model like this.

**Edit:**

I've edit and re-run the mnist file, whose code is the same as above except for those lines:

```
...

x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 784], name='input')

...

correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(y, 1), tf.argmax(y_, 1), name='result')

...
```

Then, I try to run this another .py code (in the same directory as the above code) in order to pass a local handwritten number image ("mnist-input-image.png") located in the same directory:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

image_test = Image.open("mnist-input-image.png")
image = np.array(image_test)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph('/Users/username/.meta')
    new = saver.restore(sess, tf.train.latest_checkpoint('/Users/username/'))

    graph = tf.get_default_graph()
    input_x = graph.get_tensor_by_name("input:0")
    result = graph.get_tensor_by_name("result:0")

    feed_dict = {input_x: image}

    predictions = result.eval(feed_dict=feed_dict)
    print(predictions)
```

Now, if I correctly understand,  I've to pass the image as numpy array. Then, my questions are:

1) Which is the exact file reference of those lines (since I've no .meta folder in my User folder)?

```
saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph('/Users/username/.meta')
new = saver.restore(sess, tf.train.latest_checkpoint('/Users/username/'))
```

I mean, to which exact files refer those lines (from my generated files list above)?

2) Translasted to my case, is correct this line to pass my numpy array into the feed dict?

```
feed_dict = {input_x: image}
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution is to use your session object. When you have generated the `checkpoint` file, you can restore it with a `Saver` object.

By the way, do you know why most tutorials have their graph creation inside of a function? One good reason is because you can deserialize the graph quickly with your inputs.

The correct method to start a session is with the following:

```
# Use your placeholders, variables, etc to create the entire graph.
# Usually you return the input placeholder, 
# prediction and the loss/accuracy here.
# You don't need the accuracy.
x, y, _ = make_your_graph(test_X, test_y)

# This object is the interface for serialization in tf
saver = tf.train.Saver()

with tf.Session() as sess:
    # Takes your current model's checkpoint. "./checkpoint" is your checkpoint file.
    saver.restore(sess, tf.train.latest_checkpoint("./checkpoint"))
    prediction = sess.run(y)
```

Want to run more than 1 data point for your already-booted up session?

Then replace the last line with a feed dict:

```
while waiting_for_new_y():
    another_y = get_new_y()
    feed_dict = {x: [another_y]}
    another_prediction = sess.run(y, feed_dict)
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all , give value to name parameter in each object which you want to use later , so that you can use it later by it's name:

change this :

```
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 784])
```

to

```
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 784],name='input')
```

and

```
correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(y, 1), tf.argmax(y_, 1))
```

to

```
correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(y, 1), tf.argmax(y_, 1),name='result')
```

Now run this small script to store model :

```
import tensorflow as tf
with tf.Session() as sess:
    saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph('/Users/dummy/.meta')
    new=saver.restore(sess, tf.train.latest_checkpoint('/Users/dummy/'))

    graph = tf.get_default_graph()
    input_x = graph.get_tensor_by_name("input:0")
    result = graph.get_tensor_by_name("result:0")

    feed_dict = {input_x: mnist.test.images,}  #here you feed your new data for example i am feeding mnist

    predictions = result.eval(feed_dict=feed_dict)
    print(predictions)
```

And you will get output.

Comment: I think I got the general idea, but I still have some doubts (see Edit)